# How To Add And Remove A Class To Parent Element When A String, Created By A Select Option, Is Displayed

Tags: jquery

I have a select dropdown for which each option displays a unique string below the dropdown.

This string is housed within a div with class `dropdown_text`.

I would like to add a class to the parent element that houses the dropdown if the text below the dropdown contains a certain word (being 'textstring').

The parent element is a div with class `wrap`.

So far I've been able to add the class to the parent element, but I'm just having trouble removing the class when the text below the dropdown does not contain the word 'textstring'.

Here's my jquery so far;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('change', '#product', function(){
        var userString = 'textstring';
        $('div.dropdown_text:contains('+ userString +')').closest('.wrap').addClass('new-class');
        $('div.dropdown_text:not(:contains ('+ userString +'))').closest('.wrap').removeClass('new-class');
    });
});
```

Here's some example markup;

```
<div class="wrap">
    <select id="product">
        <option>generictext</option>
        <option>textstring</option>
        <option>generictextagain</option>
    </select>
    <div class="dropdown_text">
        <p>generictext</p><!--This text changes depending on which select option from above is selected-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The actual markup in the website is much more complex than this, hence the use of of `.closest` in the jQuery. `.closest` needs to remain in place.

What am I doing wrong in the following line of my jQuery function? The class is not being removed from the parent when 'textstring' is not displayed below the dropdown.

`$('div.dropdown_text:not(:contains ('+ userString +'))').closest('.wrap').removeClass('new-class');`

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: I am using jQuery version 1.12.4. Is there something in that line of jQuery that is not supported in version 1.12.4?

Comment: what version of jQuery? Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796448/jquery-remove-class-on-closest

Comment: Working fine check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0bvhLcd6/1/)

Comment: The jQuery version is 1.12.4 
Is there something in my function that is not supported in 1.12.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by removing the space after `:contains` and `userString`, as follows;

`$('div.dropdown_text:not(:contains('+userString+'))').closest('.wrap').removeClass('new-class');`